# why Catalina using so much memory?

Tags: macos, catalina, memory

I think this is not normal memory usage. 
How can I check why this happens?

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**

After restart it dropped down

[image]

Comment: consider https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thanks for reply. Problem here is not docker. WindowServer takes more then 12GB of memory...

Comment: It seems many variables https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=catalina+windows+server+memory

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 looks like this problem exists from 2014 up to now... what a shame.. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/windowserver-lots-of-ram.1813522/post-20282563